# MongoDB Aggregation Framework $map on original document list

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have this documents:

```
[
  { "ruleId": "1", "ruleProperty": 111, "composeOfRules": [ "2", "3" ]},
  { "ruleId": "2", "ruleProperty": 222, "composeOfRules": [ "3" ]},
  { "ruleId": "3", "ruleProperty": 333, "composeOfRules": []},
]
```

I want to enrich each rule in `composeOfRules` with its `ruleProperty`:

```
[
  { "ruleId": "1", "ruleProperty": 111, "composeOfRules": [ { "ruleId": "2", "ruleProperty": 222 }, { "ruleId": "3", "ruleProperty": 333 } ]},
  { "ruleId": "2", "ruleProperty": 222, "composeOfRules": [ { "ruleId": "3", "ruleProperty": 333 } ]},
  { "ruleId": "3", "ruleProperty": 333, "composeOfRules": []},
]
```

I know that I can use `$project` with `$map` in the array, but I don't know how to use the original collection in the `input` field of `$map`:

```
$map: {
    input: ??
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you getting the first set of documents that are in your question from? I believe that @user2683814 and myself are under the impression that those documents are coming from a collection that already exists in your DB

Comment: Hi! No, there from an aggregation. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: Could you add the entire aggregation ? May be there is a better way to approach your problem ? a complete different aggregation query ?

Comment: Could you also give us an example of the original data as well? So we want fields we can work with. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @user2683814 let me know what you think. If the documents at the top of the question are the output of aggregation, could we use a project to add a field that uses $$ROOT as its value, then group by null and push together the root field into an array and combine the original field into array as well, unwind by the original fields, and finally project to get back to the original structure while also using a map-filter to change the composeOfRules field into what italktothewind wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can reference the collection in its entirety the way you seem to want to is by using a [lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) and even then that would only be the start. You would need to do a lot more then just a lookup or a map to achievement the output you are looking for.

Try this:

```
db.NameOfYourCollection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: {
        path: "$composeOfRules",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        "from": "NameOfYourCollection",
        "localField": "composeOfRules",
        "foreignField": "ruleId",
        "as": "rule"
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$rule",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        "_id": {
            "ruleId": "$ruleId",
            "ruleProperty": "$ruleProperty"
        },
        "composeOfRules": {
            "$push": "$rule"
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "ruleId": "$_id.ruleId",
        "ruleProperty": "$_id.ruleProperty",
        "composeOfRules": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$composeOfRules",
                "as": "rule",
                "in": {
                    "ruleId": "$$rule.ruleId",
                    "ruleProperty": "$$rule.ruleProperty"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

This query unwinds the array field, composeOfRules, into more manageable pieces while also preserving the record with an empty array. The lookup will get all the details of rules by the broken out composeOfRules. The results from the lookup will unwound to be more manageable for the next operation. The group will bring everything back together and merge the more detailed rules into an array. And the final project will clean up the results to look like the output you want.

**UPDATE**

If it turns out that the documents that were provided in the question are the final output of an aggregation. You could add the following to get the desired results. ( Not Tested Yet )

```
...previous operations of the aggregation...
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "ruleId": 1,
        "ruleProperty": 1,
        "composeOfRules": 1,
        "rootField": "$$ROOT"
    }
}, {
    "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "rootArray": {
            "$push": "rootField"
        },
        "originalFields": {
            "$push": {
                "ruleId": "$ruleId",
                "ruleProperty": "$ruleProperty",
                "composeOfRules": "$composeOfRules"
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unwind": "$originalFields"
}, {
    "$project": {
        "_id": 0,
        "ruleId": "$originalFields.ruleId",
        "ruleProperty": "$originalFields.ruleProperty",
        "composeOfRules": {
            "$map": {
                "input": { "$filter": {
                    "input": "$rootArray",
                    "as": "rootObj",
                    "cond": { "$in": [ "$$rootObj.ruleId", "$originalFields.composeOfRules" ] }
                } },
                "as": "rule",
                "in": { "ruleId": "$$rule.ruleId", "ruleProperty": "$$rule.ruleProperty" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem here is that I don't have a 'rules' collection, in my example it was the aggregation of other collection.

Comment: The name of the collection shouldn't matter in this case. If you were to change db.rule.aggregate to db.NameOfYourCollection.aggregate as well as change the from field in the $lookup to that same name the query will do what you are looking for it to do.